# Accessing user_struct for a particular UID

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel, android-kernel

I am hacking linux kernel and am trying to update the User_struct of a given user if given the UID. How do I access user_struct once given a UID/user id.

Answer (score 1):

Try `struct user_struct *find_user(uid_t uid)` located in `kernel/user.c`

[Here](http://androidxref.com/kernel_3.4/xref/kernel/user.c#113) is a link to its definition in the Android Linux Kernel source code.